# Loopj Post request with body

Tags: post, request, loopj

Dear all i am using [Loopj](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) and really like it. It makes my life easier. Now I want post json in the body of the post request.kindly check it what i m doing wrong my code is below.

```
params.put("SaleOrderItems", mJsonArrayOfObject.toString());
    params.put("CustomerReferenceNumber", "asdf");
    // /*mSaleOrder.getmCustomerReferenceNo()*/);
    params.put("RecordType", "HOS");
    params.put("DeliveryDate", "2012-12-28T12:04:27.3553985+01:00"); // mSaleOrder.getmDeliveryDate());
    params.put("SellToCustomerNumber", "user");
```

Then i call like this.

```
mAsyncHttpClient.post(WEBCONSTANTS.ORDER_SERVICE_SAVE_ORDER, mParams,
            new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){};
```

I got this error

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI}
```

Kindly tell me how to send json array of objects in the body of the post request using LoopJ.
best regards,

Comment: Seems like some issue with URL you are using (WEBCONSTANTS.ORDER_SERVICE_SAVE_ORDER). Please check POST using browser (extension e.g. Advanced REST Client) first

Answer (score 7):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```java
String url = "<your site url>";
JSONObject jdata = new JSONObject();
try {
    jdata.put("key1", val1);
    jdata.put("key2", val2);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // json exception
}
StringEntity entity;
try {
    entity = new StringEntity(jdata.toString());
    client.post(getBaseContext(), url, entity, "application/json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            JSONObject res;
            try {
                res = new JSONObject(response);
                Log.d("debug", res.getString("some_key")); // this is how you get a value out
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Yup but its not working  i think loopj post doesn't post complete string on server.might be it trimmed it.

Comment: The above code works for me, what error message are you getting?

Comment: **server doesn't recieve http string that i am sending in post body.
I am doing it this way,
AsyncHttpClient mAsyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
mAsyncHttpClient.addHeader("Content-Type:", "application/json");
mAsyncHttpClient.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
Gson mGson = new Gson();
final String mGSON = mGson.toJson(ObjectToSendToServer);
mAsyncHttpClient
     .post(mContext,
       "http://ServerIPAddress/SaveSaleOrderWithJson",
       (new StringEntity(mGSON)), "application/json",
       new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {}
**

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong but you can try it my way. Also you can edit the question with server code, maybe the server is something else.